# What comes next in this sequence $1,4,8,16,17,44,58,76,\dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle, prime-factorization

> My friend John asked me what is the next number in the sequence
> $$1,4,8,16,17,44,58,76,\dots ?$$
> I told him it could be anything, and I asked for a clue. He told me it involves adding numbers that have no prime factor in it more than once like $4$ or $12$ because they have a factor of the prime $2$ twice.

I’m asking for possible solutions to this puzzle not for a definite answer. I tried to look this series up on the oeis but it didn’t show up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have an idea for a possible way he got the sequence.
he could have added rows of this triangle

1

2,2

3,2,3

2,6,6,2

5,2,3,2,5

…

where its the triangle of the multiplication table but if it has an extra prime factor than it’s prime factor is taken off.

1

2,2

3,4,3

4,6,6,4

5,8,9,8,5

…

Comment: How in god’s name did you think of this so quickly lmao. It would have been eight hours before I considered the anti-diagonals of the multiplication table of $\Bbb N$

Comment: First of all please refer EOQS as well as type the math using mathjax